# How to select collection view cell to zoom in image with swift?

Tags: swift, gallery, gesture, collectionview

I'm building an app display photo as grid with collection view in Swift

I'm using two storyboards, one with collectionview for photo grid.
one storyboard for zoom in photo.

And what i want when click on 1 photo to zoom in and can swipe left - right to go to next / previous item.

The question is what is the best way to do ?

- Add one more collection view on detail storyboard and clone data from photo grid storyboard?
  use gesture to swipe left - right to select next - prev cell?
- Or i can reuse collection view from photo grid storyboard on detail storyboard?

or any other way?

I'm new with ios app.
Many tks.

[image: Photo grid storyboard]

[image: Detail view storyboard]

Answer (score 1):

In general, you use a transform to "zoom". This will toggle between no zoom and 2x. Try this on your imageView.

```
if CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(someView.transform, CGAffineTransformIdentity) {
    someView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(someView.transform, 2.0, 2.0)
} else {
    someView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}
```

ps you can trigger this with a GestureRecognizer.

Comment: so, your way is zoom in an cell and use GestureRecognizer? Image in cell is an thumbnail, and i think i will reload it with bigger image. An zoom is really good option in this case?

Comment: This is a general way to zoom any view. I was guessing that you have a custom cell class with an imageView as a member. I'd try this and eyeball the result to see if it's acceptable to you. If not, then going to the trouble of using 2 images as you say might be better.

Comment: Yeah, im using 2 images. 1 for collection view grid. 1 for detail view. data get from api. all i want it when click to enlarge photo. i still can swipe - left - right with collection view of grid storyboard

Comment: So my question is can i reuse collection view from grid collection view ? or i have to create a new one on detail photo view and add swipe-left/right gesture on it?